# How to turn computer on within same LAN via command prompt in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, lan, power

Let's say Wakeup On LAN has been enabled in BIOS on **pc01**, and it's offline.
Now I want to bring **pc01** online via command prompt from **pc02**.
Both computers on same LAN.
What's the command I could use on **pc02** command prompt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any standard Windows command to do that.

There are 3rd party tools for Windows to send packets and maybe one of those may have a command-line version.

I don't know about any from the top of my head.
(Besides, software recommendation is off-topic on SuperUser. There is a separate StackExchange site for that.)